# Generic list of generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am having some trouble designing a solution that uses command pattern but with generics. Basically, I have defined a generic interface that has just one method that returns a list of generic object.

```
public interface IExecute<T>
{
   List<T> Execute();
}

public class SimpleExecute : IExecute<int>
{
   public List<int> Execute()
   { return a list of ints... }
}

public class Main
{
   private List<IExecute<T>> ExecuteTasks; // This is not valid in C#
}
```

Since generic list of generics isn't valid, I implemented a non-generic interface IExceute and made the generic interface extend the non-generic one and was able to create a list

```
public interface IExecute {}

public interface IExecute<T> : Execute
{
   List<T> Execute();
}

private List<IExecute> ExecuteTasks;
```

However, now I am not sure how can I loop through the ExecuteTasks and call the execute method.

I have tried my best to explain the issue. Please, let me know if you need further explanation of my issue.

Thanks

Comment: If the instances of `IExecute` are not all going to be the same type, then what benefit is being provided by the generics?

Comment: So, each `Execute()` returns `List<T>` for some unknown `T`. What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: I am going to write them back to an excel spreadsheet using a class which uses reflection and type info to determine the object type and determines the name of the worksheet from the object's attribute info

Comment: @user320587 In that case, why do you even need generics? Why can't you have `interface IExecute { IList Execute(); }` and nothing else?

Comment: @svick Hmmm. that's a very valid point. Now you got me thinking clearly. I agree with you and just going to use IList. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is this:

```
public interface IExecute { IList Execute(); }
```

Then, for example:

```
public class SimpleExecute : IExecute<int>   
{   
   public List<int> Execute()   
   { return a list of ints... }   
   IList IExecute.Execute() { return this.Execute(); }
}
```

(Note the explicit interface member implementation for the non-generic `IExecute.Execute()`)

Then:

```
List<IExecute> iExecuteList = //whatever;
foreach (var ix in iExecuteList)
{
    IList list = ix.Execute();
}
```

You can't get the specific generic list type at compile time (for example, `IList<string>`, `IList<int>`) for the same reason you can't store an `int` and a `string` in the same generic list (unless the type argument is `object`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main
{
   private List<IExecute<T> ExecuteTasks; // This is not valid in C#
}
```

There are 2 errors here:

- T is an unknown class. You should have specified the correct type
- List< doesn't have a close angle bracket '>'. Each opening bracket must have a closing one. It should look like `List<IExecute<T>>`

Comment: I think the point here is that it should be a list of tasks with different `T`s.

Comment: 1. Yes, that's the whole point of the question... 2. Obviously a typo on the OP's part.

Comment: I know it's not the answer he wanted to hear, but he made some mistakes and I tried to correct them.

Comment: @HeM01: Sure.  However, it would be preferable to address these types of issues in the comments rather than as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @mellamokb: I know.. some points left to get the comment functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<IExecute<T>> ExecuteTasks
```

is not valid because T is not defined anywhere in the containing class.

Something like this should work instead though:

```
List<IExecute<Object>> ExecuteTasks;

ExecuteTasks.Add(new SimpleExecute());
```

Or

```
public class Main<T>
{
    List<IExecute<T>> ExecuteTasks 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through every item by using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var item in ExecuteTasks)
{
    item.Execute();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using generics, consider that `IExecute<Class1>` is a completely different interface than `IExecute<Class2>`. In this case, if you were to invoke a common method in both, you'd need another interface; e.g. `IExecute`.

```
public interface IExecute<T>
{
    List<T> Execute();
}

public interface IExecute
{
    IList Execute();
}

public class SimpleExecute : IExecute<int>, IExecute
{
    IList IExecute.Execute()
    {
        return Execute();
    }

    public List<int> Execute()
    {
        return new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Then, to loop you can simply use foreach and/or LINQ.

```
List<IExecute> entries = new List<IExecute> {new SimpleExecute()};

foreach (var result in entries.Select(x => x.Execute()))
{
}
```

What you are trying to achieve seems correct because you consider IExecute as a single interface, but in fact it is a "template" for an interface which will be created at compile time.